# How do I force the type of a IDREF attribute to the real target type with xjc

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2, xjc

I have written a schema that contains the following types: `Person` and `Car`. Car has an ID attribute, and Person has an IDREF attribute that refers to Car ID.

I have added bindings directives into Person so that the car attribute is a Car instead of Object, but it doesn't work (looks like the `<jxb:property>` only works for elements, not attributes ?) :

```
<xsd:complexType name="Person">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:appinfo>
      <jxb:property name="car">
        <jxb:baseType name="com.example.Car"/>
      </jxb:property>
    </xsd:appinfo>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:attribute name="car" type="xsd:IDREF"/>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="Car">
  <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

When I generate Java classes from this schema with xjc, I get the following classes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Person")
public class Person {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "car")
    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "IDREF")
    protected Object car;

    public Object getCar() {
        return car;
    }
    public void setCar(Object value) {
        this.car = value;
    }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Car")
public class Car {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlID
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "ID")
    protected String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String value) {
        this.id = value;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to tell xjc to narrow the type of Person.car to Car instead of Object ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [specify type for IDREF in XML schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285036/specify-type-for-idref-in-xml-schema)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me using an attribute. One thing to note is that I had to include the jaxb:version in the xsd declaration. Without this, the generation failed.

Xsd extract:

```
<xs:attribute name="idRef" type="xs:IDREF">
      <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                 <jaxb:property>
                    <jaxb:baseType name="PractitionerType"/>
                 </jaxb:property>
            </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
</xs:attribute>
```

Generated:

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "idRef")
@XmlIDREF
@XmlSchemaType(name = "IDREF")
protected PractitionerType idRef;
```