# Customizing xs:any jaxb mapping

Tags: jaxb

Xjc binds xs:any type in the XSD to org.w3c.dom.Element. 
If I wanted to instead customize this binding to groovy.util.Node, how would I go about it?

XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="datatype:v1" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:complexType name="ProgramDataType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any processContents="lax"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Binding:

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="datatype.xsd" node="//xs:complexType[@name='ProgramDataType']//xs:any">
      <jxb:baseType name="groovy.util.Node"/>
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: Try `jaxb:baseType`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285036/specify-type-for-idref-in-xml-schema/16289288#16289288).

Comment: @lexicore I tried the following binding - but the generated classes still had xs:any node mapped to org.w3c.dom.Element
Please see code snippet in the question.